# iOS XMPP not blocking contacts

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

i'm implementing in my app xmppFramework, now i'm working to block/unblock contacts(iq, messages, presence in/out).

This is the piece of code i use to block:

```
[_privacy addDelegate:self delegateQueue: dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)];

XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:_jidToLock];

[_roster unsubscribePresenceFromUser:jid];
[_roster revokePresencePermissionFromUser:jid];
[_roster removeUser:jid];

DDXMLElement *element = [XMPPPrivacy privacyItemWithType:@"jid" value:[jid bare] action:@"deny" order:1];

[_privacy setActiveListName:kDefaultPrivacyListName];
[_privacy setListWithName:kDefaultPrivacyListName items:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: element, nil]];
```

this works fine, in fact if I send an sms to blocked contact he is not receiving sms.

The problem is that if he text me i receive message, and if i close/reopen app seems that every contact is unblocked... any suggestions?

Comment: refer this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038630/ios-block-user-using-xep-0191/35315034#35315034